The latest package version from PPA is not available to install Ubuntu 24.04
I want to install the latest qBittorrent (5.0.3) from https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable on Ubuntu 24.04
I see that this version is available in the repo for multiple architectures:
qbittorrent    1:5.0.3.99~202412290749-8437-35dce07c6~ubuntu24.10.1    qBittorrent Team (2024-12-29)
But for some reason, my apt shows this even after updating repos:
~ sudo apt upgrade qbittorrent
qbittorrent is already the newest version (1:4.6.7.99~202411110115-8155-91943e481~ubuntu24.04.1).

~ sudo apt-cache policy qbittorrent
qbittorrent:
  Installed: 1:4.6.7.99~202411110115-8155-91943e481~ubuntu24.04.1
  Candidate: 1:4.6.7.99~202411110115-8155-91943e481~ubuntu24.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.6.7.99~202411110115-8155-91943e481~ubuntu24.04.1 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.6.3-1build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 Packages

Why is it not available to install?
I think I can manually download and install the .deb but why it's not showing up?

You need to filter the list to see which version of qbittorrent is available for your release of Ubuntu.
Also the version-number 1:5.0.3.99~202412290749-8437-35dce07c6~ubuntu24.10.1 indicates a package for 24.10 which isn't the release your using.
If you want version 5.0.3, it's available as a snap:
~$ snap info qbittorrent-desktop-tak
name:      qbittorrent-desktop-tak
summary:   UnOfficial release of qBittorrent for Desktop (with graphical UI)
publisher: TehAppKiller (tak)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/qbittorrent-desktop-tak
contact:   tehappkiller@proton.me
license:   MIT
description: |
  **qBittorrent is a free and open-source BitTorrent client** based on the Qt toolkit and
  libtorrent-rasterbar library.
  
  * This is the desktop version with graphical UI ; for server version (qbittorrent-nox) with only
  webUI see https://snapcraft.io/qbittorrent-tak
  * See https://www.qbittorrent.org for more details.
  
  **qBittorrent Release 5+**
  * /home folder is accessible
  * Snap dependencies required: kf6-core22, gtk-common-themes
  
  **!!! Files can only be written in a directory owned by 'user' (not by 'root') !!!**
  
  This is due to current behavior and restrictions of snaps by Canonical.\
  Please use Server edition if you need to write in 'root'-owned folders:
  https://snapcraft.io/qbittorrent-tak
snap-id: 1EKgQ3FZaNtmXeLA7aTkKmBAkCV42ooU
channels:
  latest/stable:    5.0.3    2024-12-18 (2) 72MB -
  latest/candidate: 5.0.3    2024-12-18 (2) 72MB -
  latest/beta:      5.0.3    2024-12-18 (2) 72MB -
  latest/edge:      5.0.3-v2 2024-12-18 (4) 72MB -


You are right, I missed that it's available for 24.10 not 24.04. Thanks for catching it.
